# How to access the left channel level and right channel level separately from microphone input

Tags: actionscript-3, audio-streaming

I am using [this code snippet](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d0c) to trace the activityLevel (basically volume) from the microphone. Basically, this shows an integer by using

```
function onMicActivity(event:ActivityEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("activating=" + event.activating + ", activityLevel=" +  
        mic.activityLevel); 
}
```

According to [Adobe's ActionScript 3.0 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#activityLevel), the activityLevel property only outputs a single integer between 0 and 100. How can I get volume levels of the left channel and the right channel separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the appropriate answer is `user = upCreek - paddle;`. See Adobe's statement on the subject:

> ["... keep in mind that the Microphone object captures monophonic samples ..."](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html#WS184831AF-B842-4d52-BFB9-D7601F4A9E21)